# Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in C

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys i want to **use multiple checkboxes and insert their value into database but i received this error saying: `'Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in C';`

below is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('db_conn.php'); $cat=$_POST['cat'];

if(isset($_FILES['file_upload']) && isset($cat))
{
    $shuff=str_shuffle("ABD6565LSLFKDSAJFD");   

    $food = join(', ', $_POST['food']);     

    mkdir("upload/$shuff");

    $files=$_FILES['file_upload'];  

    for($x = 0; $x <count($files['name']); $x++)    
    {
        $name=$files['name'][$x];    
        $tmp_name=$files['tmp_name'][$x];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/$shuff/".$name))
        {
            $query="INSERT INTO image(mid, cid, name, food, path) VALUES('', '$cat', '$name', '$food', 'upload/$shuff/$name')";
            mysql_query($query);
            echo 'The file '.$name. ' uploaded successfully'. '<br \>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'uploading failed';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but you really need to look into using `mysql_real_escape_string`, this has SQL injections in it which are a very dangerous vulnerability.

Comment: You should seriously look into PDO instead of mysql_*, as this library is being deprecated in an upcoming release of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

try using implode instead of join:

```
if( !empty($_POST['food']) AND is_array($_POST['food']) ) {    
   $food = implode(', ', $_POST['food']); 
}
else {
  $food = "";
}
```

Comment: sorry where to use it and what is is_array functionality

Comment: @TariqHashemee make a habit of checking docs... glad it worked for you.. :)

Comment: @TariqHashemee btw you might consider Accepting the answer if it worked for you...