# Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed (PHP/MySQL Query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? I get the error message "Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in..." on the very last line - echo join( $URL, '
' );

I checked [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607601/warning-join-function-join-invalid-arguments-passed-in-c) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374881/invalid-arguments-passed-join), but nothing clicks. I pasted my query into phpMyAdmin > SQL, and it works perfectly, returning a table with two columns listing values in the field URL that have multiple instances along with the number of instances (e.g. Bill_Gates | 4).

So it looks like there must be a problem with my code - unless there's a bug in a file higher up the food chain, but I don't think that's likely.

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("select URL, count(*)
from ((SELECT 'GZ' AS GSiteID, NULL as Site, 'Life' AS GSection, GZL.Taxon AS URL
       FROM gz_life GZL WHERE GZL.Taxon = :MyURL
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'All' AS GSiteID, NULL as Site, 'World' AS GSection, GG.Name AS URL
       FROM gw_geog GG WHERE GG.Name = :MyURL
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'PX' AS GSiteID, Site, 'People' AS GSection, Ppl.URL
       FROM people Ppl WHERE Ppl.URL = :MyURL
      )
     ) t
group by URL
having count(*) > 1;");
 $stm->execute(array(
 'MyURL'=>$MyURL
 ));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $URL = $row['URL'];
}

echo join( $URL, '<br>' );
```

P.S. I posted var_dump($URL); at the very end of the above script, but it only displays string(9) "Zachaenus", which doesn't make any sense to me. (I think Zachaenus is a scientific name from the table Life.) But I've never used var_dump before so maybe I'm not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the glue parameter first.

```
echo join( '<br>',$URL );
           ^^^^^  ^^^^   //<---- Order Interchanged
```

Alternatively, you could make use of [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) which does the same of the join.

Secondly.. the `$URL` must be array.

```
$URL = array();
while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 array_push($URL,$row['URL']);
}
```

Comment: That's weird; I get the same results. I normally use echo join after an ARRAY, like this...

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $URL[] = $row['URL'];
}

But the array brackets - [] - apparently don't work with this kind of query. I'll do some research on implode and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: The `$URL` must be an array for the `join` or `implode` to work. Have you modified `$URL` inside your while loop as `$URL[]` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with and without the brackets, using both echo join and implode. But let me run through my tests again, to make sure I didn't do something wrong...

Comment: Yes, that works...

$URL = array();
while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 array_push($URL,$row['URL']);
}

echo join('<br>', $URL);

Answer (score 1):

My guess is `join` is looking for a `array` and not a `string` which you are giving it and you got the `glue` and `pieces` flipped so try the following

[join](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) is an alias of [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) which is looking for `join|implode( string $glue , array $pieces )`

```
while ($row = $stm->fetch()){
    $URL[] = $row['URL'];
       #^^
}

echo join('<br>', $URL);
```

`$URL[]` this will give you a array and not a string which is being replaced every time the while loop executes and only giving you the last element from $row.

According to this [Problem with: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5879675/1700963) it says something like you might have initialized `$URL` to a `string` or some other type other than a `array` and need to change it to `$URL = array();` or use a different variable name.

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the error message "Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in..." on the line $URL[] = $row['URL'];